# Error instantiating private int

Tags: java, int, private

an `illegal start of expression` error comes up for a private int instantiation. All my `()` and `{}` are closed and previous statements have been ended with `;`. Is there any common reason for this?

```
private int starting = start;

StringCoder_Driver.java:138: error: illegal start of expression
      private int starting = start;
```

Comment: Post more code than that, and also format it correctly

Comment: Consider providing more context through the use of a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @ben sharrer where did you write this code?inside a method ?or

Comment: You can't use `private` inside a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a integer to a string.  You must initialize the integer.

Comment: Which string? Where did you see that?

Comment: private int is declaring an integer variable named starting, then making it equal start, which is a string.

Comment: How do you know that `start` is a string? I don't see a declaration so it can be everything. The error message does not give a hint in that direction either.